# Raycasting floor texture distortion problem

Tags: 3d, raycasting

I'm currently working on a raycaster in construct 2.

The FOV is 90 degrees with a screen resolution of 199 x 174. I used [this tutorial](https://wynnliam.github.io/raycaster/news/tutorial/2019/04/09/raycaster-part-03.html) when it comes to the floor raycasting.

The floors seem to render properly seam-wise, if that makes sense, but the textures themselves (for each square of the floor if you will) appears distorted in a circular motion. I think this happens when it comes to the part of displaying the correct part of the texture.

The tutorial towards the end says that it is to pick a pixel of the texture using

```
floor_point.x = player.x + cos(alpha) * d

floor_point.y = player.y - sin(alpha) * d
```

with `alpha` being the angle of the ray cast relative to the player (I believe, correct me if I'm wrong, I'm not 100% sure if `alpha` is actually the ray angle), and `d` being the distance of the floor point. I believe this is where I have a problem when it comes to determining the part of the texture to display.

How mine works is that the floor itself is a 32 x 32 tilemap with each tile being 1 pixel, having a range of 1024 tiles. I obtain the floor point X and floor point Y, they are modded to 32 since that is the texture width and multiplied to each other, so the tile it picks can be a range of 1024.

With the FOV being 90 and screen width being 199, the distance to projection plane is 199/tan(45) which equals to 122.856555133. The player height is set to 32.

The formula below is used to determine the pixel (tile for the tilemap) for each floor point.

```
  (player.x + cos(ray.angle) * ((playerheight * 122.856555133 / (floorpoint.y) / Cos(abs(ray.angle - player.Angle))))%32) 
* (player.y - sin(ray.angle) * ((playerheight * 122.856555133 / (floorpoint.y) / Cos(abs(ray.angle - player.Angle))))%32)
```

Here's what the original texture is supposed to be displayed as

[image]

Here's what the floor looks like

[image]

and here's the same problem but the square size is bigger to make it more clear

[image]

Is modding the X and Y points to 32 what may be causing the problem? I'm not sure what math is incorrect here unless I did get the "alpha" variable from the tutorial confused with something else.

Comment: Please note that there was some "errors" with parenthesis in your formula; I "removed" it but you might want to double check it. You should probably review it anyway to make it a bit more understandable to users (e.g. present it in a way that we do not need to scroll or something..).